# Lftp --newer-than is downloading empty directories

Tags: linux, sftp, lftp

I am trying to use lftp to download only new files files from a remote sftp server to the local server

This is what I am doing:

```
lftp sftp://user@remoteserver
```

cd to the directory then:

```
mirror --newer-than=now-1day --verbose
```

it downloads the new files (YaY!) but it also downloads every child directory of the parent  directory. No files though just the names of the directories:

```
Transferring file `secret.pdf'
Transferring file `secret 2.pdf'                                    
Making directory `Created'                                                                           
Making directory `old 2019'                                                  
Making directory `backups of data'                                                                    
Making directory `to test'                                                  
Total: 4 directories, 43 files, 0 symlinks                                                 
New: 2 files, 0 symlinks
7019832 bytes transferred in 28 seconds (246.6 KiB/s)
To be removed: 0 directories, 1 file, 0 symlinks
```

Also the directories are not new they have been in there for months as `ls` tells me

```
drwxrwxr-x    2 user    user        4096 Apr  8 00:28 Created
```

Sure I can use `--no-empty-dirs` and it will only download the new files getting rid of the empty directories, but why is this happening in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Because `--newer-than` affects files only. So when `lftp` finds a folder on the server that does not exist locally, it creates the local mirror. Only then it enters the folder and searches the files. It finds no file that matches your criteria. Nothing is downloaded, and you get the empty folder.

The `--no-empty-dirs` or `mirror:no-empty-dirs` modifies the behaviour, so that the local folder is created only when it's really needed to download some file.